# python- open pure pdf pages in python gui , without converting them in images

Tags: python, pdf

I am making a simple pdf viewer but I am converting pdf pages to images and then viewing but I want to open pure pdf pages in my graphical user interface.
can someone help me for this?

Comment: Add some code here

Comment: Your question is way too broad. Look for solutions, when you're stuck (with a development related question) come back here and ask for help, showing what you've tried, where you're stuck etc...